# How do I change my appearance?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

When I was creating the character my computer froze and I had to close the window with the game. When I logged again, my character appearance was just like the bald-bearded default character.

Is it possible to change my appearance? I have heard that there is an NPC that can change my appearance for a fee.

Comment: I've cleaned up the question quite a bit to fit the format of the site better. Feel free to roll it back if you don't agree with it. However, in the future, try to keep it short and simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was changed in an update for OSRS.

Now, you need to visit a few different NPCs to completely change your appearance

- The Makeover Mage in the above answer will now only change gender and skin colour
- A Hairdresser (one can be found in Falador, by the West Bank) can change your hair style and colour, and beard style and colour for males.
- The Tailor in Varrock will change your top and trousers.
- The shoe store in Rellekka will change your default boots (the boots you see when you don't have other boots equipped).

Answer (score 5):

If you leave Falador through the south gate and head towards the Crafting Guild, you'll find the [Make-over Mage](https://runescape.wiki/w/Make-over_Mage). For a fee of 3000gp you can change your appearance: this includes your skin color, hairstyles and default clothing. You can even change your gender!

[image: He's found in the upper left of the screenshot]

Note that you can also take the shortcut by the broken wall near the Falador west bank, or by climbing under the south wall behind the jewelry shop. These require Agility level 5 and 26 respectively. Note that the shortcuts require you to be on a members-only world.

Comment: Forgot to mention that it's members only? I went all the way there and I can't access it on a non-member world. Might want to clarify that so others don't make the same trip.

Comment: It shouldn't be members only, though. Only the Agility shortcuts will require you to be on a members world. The Make-over Mage isn't inside the gated members area that connects Falador to Taverly. If you check the linked wiki page, it also says it's available for F2P players.